# Executing command using su on android doesn't work

Tags: android, linux, bash, shell, root

I have rooted my android device and am trying to run the echo command in Terminal Emulator.

When i am in superuser mode ,i can run it without any issue:

`root@wsvga:/# echo "gg"`

However,when i try to run it without being in superuser mode:

`u0@wsvga:/$ su -c echo "gg"`

It returns :**[-] Execute command failed**

And when i run the same thing without the argument "gg" it works just fine.

`u0@wsvga:/$ su -c echo`

I can't see where the problem is.

Comment: `su - user -c 'command "arg"'`

Answer (score 1):

you need to use sudo and quotations as in an example, or just execute  `su -`

```
$ sudo su -c "echo test"
test

┌-(hi@yourserver)-[~]
└─$ sudo su - -c echo test
su: user test does not exist or the user entry does not contain all the required fields

┌──(hi㉿yourserver)-[~]
└─$ sudo su -c "whoami"
root

┌──(hi㉿yourserver)-[~]
└─$ su -c "whoami"
Password:
root
```

Its to do with the fact that it trys to run it from root user
and it will give you the auth error as it needs you to type in the root superuser password and that you are not using quotes on "echo ......"

```
 sudo - 
 passwd 
 password 
 password
```